# C++ syntax help, using templates

Tags: c++, templates

It is probably some stupid syntax mistake, i have the following class written in h file

```
#include "IGenticSolverHelper.h"
template <class T>
class GenericGeneticSolver
{
public:
    GenericGeneticSolver(IGenticSolverHelper<T>& helper, int generationSize) : mSolverHelper(helper)
    {
        mSolverHelper.GenerateFirstGeneration(0, generationSize, currentGeneration);
    }
private :
    vector<T> currentGeneration;
    IGenticSolverHelper<T>& mSolverHelper;
};
```

And then the following code :

```
#include "IGenticSolverHelper.h"
#include "GenericGeneticSolver.h"

class HelperImpl : IGenticSolverHelper<int>
{
public:
    void GenerateFirstGeneration(const int seed,const int generationSize, vector<int>& firstGeneration) 
    {
    }
    void Crossover(const int& father,const int& mother, int& son) 
    {
    }
    void Mutate(const int& orignal, int& mutated)
    {
    }
    float Cost(int& solution)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    int a =5;
    GenericGeneticSolver<int> mySolver(HelperImpl,a);
}
```

And i get the following error when i compile :

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'a'
```

if i will change the line to :

```
GenericGeneticSolver<int> mySolver(HelperImpl);
```

it will compile, though the constructor expect 2 arguments, and will get the following warning :

```
warning C4930: 'GenericGeneticSolver<T> mySolver(HelperImpl)': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)
```

And to add to the oddness, when i put a break point on this line, he won't stop there.

What am i doing wrong, i just trying to create an instance of `GenericGeneticSolver`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this line:

```
GenericGeneticSolver<int> mySolver(HelperImpl,a);
```

The compiler is confused about what you're trying to do here because `HelperImpl` is the name of a type, while `a` is the name of an object. The compiler thinks what you're doing is trying to prototype a function named `mySolver` that takes in a parameter of type `HelperImpl` and a parameter of type `a`, but then gets stuck because it doesn't know of any types named `a`.

If you remove `a`, you get this:

```
GenericGeneticSolver<int> mySolver(HelperImpl);
```

This is a perfectly legal prototype of a function called `mySolver` that takes an argument of type `HelperImpl` and returns a `GenericGeneticSolver<int>`. The warning you're getting is the compiler telling you that you might not have meant to make this a prototype, since it somewhat looks like an instantiation of a variable named `mySolver` but isn't.

Since I assume that you're trying to instantiate an object of type `GenericGeneticSolver<int>` here, you probably want to instantiate a `HelperImpl` and then pass that object into the constructor, like this:

```
HelperImpl hi;
GenericGeneticSolver<int> mySolver(hi, a);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, i didn't noticed that i pass a type and not an instance !

Comment: We call them _declarations_ in C++, not "prototypes". GCC's C++ front-end is senile in this regard.